# Need to control access to my files in unix

Tags: unix, ln

A front end utility calls a Unix script through putty which copy/edit/tar the files for the user. Each User has specific roles only i.e. copy or edit the files and this is controlled by the same Unix script itself.

I face security issues if a User logs on to putty by himself and tries to perform the operations that he is not authorized to do.(Backdoor)

I am looking for a way that I can do in my script when it gets called from frontend that records some activity whenever file gets updated/edited/deleted  through the Backdoor.

Comment: It is unclear what your scenario actually is. If we interpret your vague description such that you launch a full fledged `putty` client _on the users system_, then you hand out all control you had to that user. How should that unix server even tell apart authorized and not authorized usage? That is impossible. Which means that your whole approach is wrong.

Comment: I am not asking to restrict the usage at application level, but instead whenever any operation that is done through front-end tool(even though it uses putty) the timestamps of new files could be recorded/links could be created etc.. which if audited could be crosschecked. I am looking for that best thing that can be done to ensure if the backdoor is taken, then it gets reported.

Comment: Why not use a clean and secure approach instead of trying to detect symptoms? Access to the unix system should certainly _never_ be able to users in such manner which means that the authorized access should be done in a centralized way: your "front end" (what ever that is) routes legitim requests through an authorization layer (maybe a service provider, an API, what ever). That way _all_ access can be controlled, direct access from the user system can be completely blocked. This is just a simple, crude suggestion, to sketch a more elegant approach additional information is required.

Comment: @arkascha: I cannot restrict the direct access from the user because frontend is a utility that ease up a set of tasks for them and not all of them.

Comment: As already set: route those requests / tasks through some gateway you control. That is a standard solution, reliable, secure.